# Trying to work out how to play this segment

Tags: theory, sheet-music, saxophone

I’m trying to work out how to play a segment on Saxophone. The piece is Gerry Rafferty’s famous solo but I can’t remember what one detail is. It’s like a slur but only on one note.[image]

Trying to work out what this is and more importantly, how to play it.

Comment: It's not Gerry Rafferty's solo on 'Baker Street': the sax was played by  Raphael Ravenscroft.

Comment: At very least give *Raphael Ravenscroft* some credit..! And that bit wasn't even written by Rafferty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the sign means a lip-bend. That measure is played by playing the A and then re-articulating the note by dropping the pitch briefly and immediately coming back up to pitch. The effect sounds a bit like "wah-wah".
If you listen to Raphael Ravencroft's solo on the original recording of 'Baker Street' it's obvious.

In general the sign is used for a 'scoop': starting the note below pitch (as much as a semitone) and then coming up to pitch.

Answer (score 3):

It's like if you were playing trombone, you'd deflect the slide slightly flat of the note, then bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

These should be an instruction for a pitch bend. [This site](https://composerstubaguide.blog/contemporary-techniques/lips/iv-lip-bends/) calls it Lip Bend.

Though I myself don't play wind instruments, my wife does and she says, that the note you encircled, is to be played in a way that it starts a little below from its denoted value. So if your note is an `a` you may begin from (e.g.) `g#` and end in `a`.